# Access Thumbnail image outside the image folder

Tags: html, image, thumbnails, dreamweaver

I need to create a thumbnail but the issues is that this image is new and only available to this page only and no need to create a new file. What I did is that i save the copy of this image to the root folder which is outside of my image folder but when i did the test it gives the error message[

HTML

```
<a href="test.jpg" ><img border="0" src="images/Chateau/LeLagon.jpg" width="293" height="172"></a>
```

This is the image file:

[image]

Did i do the right way to save the image to my root folder?.what is the correct way to access image thumbnail in html? Is it possible to do this?

Comment: You can use base64 encoded inline images. <img alt="Embedded Image" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIA..." />

Comment: where is your page relative to the root folder?

Comment: I have updated the descriptions and i have upload the image file which descripe my root and image folder

Comment: You say nothing about where the actual HTML file is relative to the image.

Comment: The actual  image has been uploaded and displayed on "xxx.asp" page..all i want when user point or hit  the image[lnk] its thumbnail displayed

Comment: Is the naming of the image correct? I noticed in your screenshot the thumbnail is called "Test.jpg" however, in your HTML it is "test.jpg". It might be a simple case-sensitivity issue.